# list push_back a struct which includes string type core

Tags: c++, string, stl

I write a sample code and when the list push_back it always caused coredump
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
struct FDTinstance
{
    int type;
    unsigned int expirestime;
    unsigned int fileTOI;
    string filename;
    unsigned int contentlength;
    unsigned long long T3; 
    unsigned long long T1; 
    unsigned long long T4; 
    unsigned long long sessionstarttime;
};
struct PacketInfo
{
    unsigned int port;
    unsigned long long arrivetime;
    unsigned int syncType;
    unsigned short timeStamp;
    unsigned short packNum;
    unsigned int packCount;
    unsigned int TSI;
    unsigned int TOI;
    FDTinstance fDTinstance;
};
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct PacketInfo packet;
    packet.fDTinstance.filename = "http://123.com";
    packet.syncType=1;
    packet.fDTinstance.expirestime = 100;
    packet.fDTinstance.fileTOI = 0;
    struct PacketInfo pack;
    memcpy(&pack, &packet, sizeof(packet));
    mVodList.push_back(pack);//cause core
    return 0;
}
```

If I use `const char* filename` ,the program is OK. But when I use string type the program will core at `push_back()`. I don't kown why .Thanks

Comment: The problem is not the `push_back`, it  is the `memcpy`. You really don't want to be using that.

Comment: push_back actually pushes a copy of the object you pass anyway, so skip using `pack` at all, and just `mVodList.push_back(packet);` and be done with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `memcpy` and do this:

```
PacketInfo pack = packet;
```

or even better, forget about the intermediate copy altogether and do this:

```
mVodList.push_back(packet); // stores a copy of packet
```

The reason is that `memcpy` only works for POD types, and `std::string` is not one of those. In any case, even for PODs, using the copy constructor or assignment operator is the idiomatic way of copying one object into another one.

Also note that in C++ you don't need to write `struct` all over the place. So why say this

```
struct PacketInfo packet;
```

when you can say this?

```
PacketInfo packet;
```

Comment: Thanks I konw the root cause.But I need to copy packet to pack.But I think "PacketInfo pack = packet" can not copy the object.

Comment: @Ericzhang88120 yes it does.

Comment: @Ericzhang88120 that is how you copy things in C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
memcpy(&pack,&packet,sizeof(packet));
```

That's not a valid way to copy non-POD objects, and there's no reason to use it for POD objects either.  Just use the assignment operator (`operator=`).  Or the copy constructor.